# returning a value from a MySQL function

Tags: mysql, sql, function

I wrote a small function:

```
CREATE TABLE states
    (`id` int, `name` varchar(2))
;

INSERT INTO states
    (`id`, `name`)
VALUES
    (1, 'md'),
    (2, 'tx'),
    (3, 'ma')
;

delimiter //

create function states_repeated (s varchar(2))
returns int
begin
  insert into sid select count(*) from states where states.name=s ;
  return sid ;
end//

delimiter ;

select states_repated('ma') ;
```

But this returns

```
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'test.sid' doesn't exist
```

How do I return this value?

Comment: Change INSERT with SELECT in `insert count(*) into sid from states where states.state=s;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like this,

```
DECLARE _returnValue INT;
SET _returnValue = (select count(*) from states where states.state = s);
return _returnValue;
```

the full code

```
delimiter //

create function states_repeated (s varchar(2))
returns int
begin
    DECLARE _returnValue INT;
    SET _returnValue = (select count(*) from states where states.name = s);
    return _returnValue;
end//

delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 0):

i think mysql functions and stored procedures just return the declared variable